# How to get the 1st match between 2 string arrays

Tags: c#, linq, string-matching, string-comparison, arrays

I have 2 string arrays. The one is the base and the other is changing.

```
string[] baseArray = { "Gold", "Silver", "Bronze" };
string[] readArray = { "Bronze", "Silver", "Gold" };

// After comparing the readArray over the baseArray the result should be this
//string match = "Gold";
```

I want to get the 1st in order of the baseArray.

```
//Example2
string[] readArray = { "Bronze", "Silver" };
//string match should be "Silver"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only want one result, using LINQ:

```
string firstMatch = baseArray.FirstOrDefault(readArray.Contains);
```

If you only want one result, not using LINQ:

```
string firstMatch = null;
foreach(string element in baseArray)
{
    if (Array.IndexOf(readArray, element) >= 0)
    {
        firstMatch = element;
        break;
    }
}
```

If you want all matching elements, using LINQ:

```
string[] common = baseArray.Intersect(readArray).ToArray();
```

If you want all matching elements, not using LINQ:

```
HasSet<string> common = new HashSet<string>(readArray);
result.Intersect(baseArray);
```

Comment: +1 Better solution than mine. I would do a `FirstOrDefault()` in the end, though.

Comment: He wants the first match not all.

Comment: I want the 1st in order string from the baseArray though im gonna give it a try.

Comment: @MartinMulder: Since `Intersect` is efficient and  is implemented by using deferred execution i would use it with `FirstOrDefault`. So: `baseArray.Intersect(readArray).FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: @Tim: Interesting idea. I would like to measure performance of both solutions, but not tonight. Im am going to bed now! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var match = baseArray.FirstOrDefault(x => readArray.Contains(x));
```

Comment: contains might give false results maybe i could use equals.

Comment: @Incognito `.Contains()` uses `.Equals()` behind the scenes. If one is failing then both are.

Comment: @Incognito. Why should it be failing? Because of the cultures?

Comment: I meant in my case because the sting arrays are not exactly that its an example. for example the readArray can contain "Gold-Word" "Gold-Word2" etc and it will fail i want to check which exact index of the array it was.

Comment: @Incognito I'm using `.Contains()` to find the items in the list, not doing `string.Contains()` to find whether a string contains another string. That's got nothing to do with it.